# Click image to launch HTML5 Video in a next window

Tags: html, html5-video

I have some html5 video that I want to use on my website. However I want to launch or start the video in a new window after you click an image link, of course I want the video to have controls and such in the new window. How can this be done? The code I am currently using is below.

```
<video id=0 controls width=640 height=360>
<source src="Kingz Of Da City.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
<source src="Kingz Of Da City.webm" type='video/webm' >
<source src="Kingz Of Da City.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<p>Video is not visible, most likely your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

Comment: @Zeaklous I haven't tried anything as I haven't seen code to open html5 video in a next window anywhere

Comment: There are questions related with how to open other webpages, you'd just need to have the page show the video. If you mean to open the video on the current page look for video overlay questions, there a multiple

Answer (score 0):

**What you need is Sandwich page markup method**

To strat with you need to create some php pages, such as head.php, player.php, body.php and those landing page for an example page1.php, page2.php  e.t.c

**inside your head.php write this:**

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['v'])){
$video=$_REQUEST['v'];} 
?>
```

**inside your player.php write this:**

```
<video id=0 controls width=640 height=360>
<source src="mediaFolder/<?php echo $video ?>.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
<source src="mediaFolder/<?php echo $video ?>.webm" type='video/webm' >
<source src="mediaFolder/<?php echo $video ?>.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<p>Video is not visible, most likely your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

**inside your body.php or any where you want to use your link-out write this:**

```
<a href="page1.php?v=myvidename1"><img  src="linkImgs/poster1.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""></a>
<a href="page2.php?v=myvidename2"><img  src="linkImgs/poster2.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""></a>
<a href="page3.php?v=myvidename3"><img  src="linkImgs/poster3.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""></a>
```

Save all created pages in your root directory.

**Next>>>>>>>>**

This is your sandwich  template (with the burger) this will go into each blank page such as that of home page, page1, page2 and page3

```
<div class="header">
  <?php include('head.php'); ?>
</div>


<div class="mainBody">
  <div class="playerArea">
    <?php include('player.php'); ?>
  </div>
  <?php include('body.php'); ?>
</div>


<div class="footer">
  <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</div>
```

What then happen is that whenever any of these images are clicked it send a signal to the head.php telling him the video name>> head received the signal and report>> to player.php (echo out the video name), HTML5 player triggers and play the video.

The sample  template above  is the basic of any CMS on the web . Such as that of YouTube (where you have something like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEsTd_a3WLQ ), WordPress, Twitter , Facebook name them.
**I think we are done**